# hts R package forecasted values

Tags: r, forecasting, hts

I was using the hts R package for hierarchical forecasting and I want to obtain or extract the forecasted values into a data frame, for example:

```
library(hts)
data <- window(htseg2, start = 1992, end = 2002)
test <- window(htseg2, start = 2003)
fcasts <- as.data.frame(forecast(data, h = 5, method = "bu"))
plot(fcasts)
```

[image]
which plots the forecasted values in dotted lines, implying that somehow they can be extracted however, the `fcasts` object does not store such information.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forecasts are saved efficiently, but if you want all of them, they can be computed using `allts()` and then converted to a data frame as follows.

```
as.data.frame(allts(forecast(data, h = 5, method = "bu")))
```